# Implicitly linked "partner" pages

Tags: discussion, privacy

Today I realized that by simply reading pages on SO, also some address of *.facebook.com is accessed. Maybe it was graphs.facebook.com

I never found any mentioning to that end on the [Privacy Policy page](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy).

So my question: Is there a *simple* overview what other "partners" SO has and provides access information to?

Comment: Is that not just for the Facebook share option?

Comment: It might be the profile image for users signed in through facebook.